# Ng-select dropdown is partially hide inside mat-expansion-panel?

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu

I am using Ng-select dropdown but is partially hide inside mat-expansion-panel.
I tried many solutions but none of them works.
There is an approach:

appendTO="body"

But here the problem is that the moment that when the dropdown is open it moves up or down on the page if you move the scroller of the page.
Please if you have any suggestions I would appreciate them.

Comment: Do you have a stackblitz or any example code?

Comment: give me a second

Comment: i edit the sample code is there

Comment: Without the appendTo="body" the problem is, that the z-index is limited to its parent. I dont know your application around that, but it might be a bit difficult if not impossible to change all the z-indices neccessary in order to get that working when rendering it in place.

With the appendTo="body" the z-index issue is gone, but you are fixed on the page. Is it possible to deactivate scrolling in that moment?

Comment: is ther any way to change the height of the parent at least when the drop-down is open

Comment: i don't understand where to use appendTO="body" ?

Comment: For reference, this happens because `.mat-expansion-panel` defines `overflow: hidden`. Changing to `overflow: visible` for the specific panel helps as a work-around. However, the overall height of the page might grow beyond the end of the footer when the panel is closed (i.e., you might see empty vertical space at the end of the page due to the invisible content of the panel).